# How to make the text bigger in aChartEngine?

Tags: android, text, charts, achartengine

I use aChartEngine in my app, but I've a problem, the XLabels' text is unreadable, they've a short size and are confused with the bar. How can I make bigger the text and move them a bit to the right? This is an image of my GraphicView.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set label text size as follows

```
 mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15); // 15
```

Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067642/label-text-size-according-to-the-screen-size-in-a-chart-engine-pie-chart-in-andr)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know also how to move a little the text?