# How to Increase X or Y axis label sizes in AChartEngine in Android and Enable zoom

Tags: android, fonts, zooming, achartengine

I have the whole line chart working. However the fonts are really small for the labels in x axis and y axis and also on the points where it is plotted. I've circled them in the picture in order to let you know what labels I am talking about.

Also I have disabled the zoom buttons, however we can still zoom using our fingers on the screen. When I zoom in the chart gets messed up. How do I not allow any kind of zooming?

[image]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Your answer is here  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067642/label-text-size-according-to-the-screen-size-in-a-chart-engine-pie-chart-in-andr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set labels size in pixels for 2 axis together

```
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(float textSize)
```

Also you can set label color, align gor X and Y axis, for example:

```
renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color color);
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
```

Comment: In above attached screen shot can resize "Amount in Dollar".   ?